# Covariance and Contravariance Confusion

Tags: c#, .net, covariance, contravariance

I am confused on how contravariant/covariance works with C#. I have the following pseudo code

```
public static void Main()
{
    Action<string> action = e => Console.WriteLine(e);
    Execute(action);
}

private static void Execute(Action<object> action)
{
    action("hello world");
}
```

which throws

> CS1502: The best overloaded method match for [...] has some invalid arguments

and I am not exactly sure why. also, what would be the correct way to do this?

In my real scenario I have a base interface I use instead of object passing in concrete instances.

Thanks!

Comment: I edited your post to include the exception message you provided. Please re-edit it, filling the `[...]` placeholder with the real message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Action<in T>` is *contravariant*, meaning you can pass "bigger" types into the method. Because `string` is a smaller (more specific, or derived) than `object`, you get a compile time error. If you reversed your example, and created an `Action<object>` instead of `Action<string>`, your method would compile:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Action<object> action = e => Console.WriteLine(e);
    Execute(action);
}

private static void Execute(Action<string> action)
{
    action("hello world");
}
```

Comment: I like the description for the type parameter `T` in the documentation for [`Action<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): *"This type parameter is contravariant. That is, you can use either the type you specified or any type that is less derived."*

Answer (score 3):

`Action`s and `Func`s are contravariant in their argument types - this means that you can only assign an `Action<T>` to an `Action<U>` if `U` is a subtype of `T`. In your case, `object` is a supertype of `string` so the assignment is invalid.